# How to change the width of the frame of a view in a NIB file when view loads to fit the screen width

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my original post about getting the scrollView working in the first place: [ScrollView in NIB File Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172893/scrollview-in-nib-file-swift). 
My new problem is that when the external, long view I put into the scrollview is loaded on any ios device smaller than an iPhone 6+ it doesn't fit the width. I tried to change the width of the view in the viewDidLoad but it says: "Cannot assign to the result of this expression."

GitHub Link: https://github.com/frodgers1207/Testing-ScrollViews

```
class ScrollViewVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewImageContainer: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var imageContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageOne: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageTwo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageThree: UIImageView!

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    //set the tab bar item's title
}
convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName: "ScrollViewVC", bundle: nil)
}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    contentView.frame.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width //Error Here: "Cannot assign to the result of this expression"
    self.mainScrollView.contentSize.height = self.contentView.frame.height
    self.mainScrollView.contentSize.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    self.contentViewImageContainer.addSubview(self.imageContainer)
    self.contentViewImageContainer.contentSize = self.imageContainer.frame.size
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Edit: Will I need to create a custom UIView with an init of a frame? Would that allow me to resize the width of my UIView at runtime depending on the device?

[image: Layout in Interface Builder]

This is how the nib file looks. Each screenshot is a top level view and I add them into each other when the view loads to give a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is it a compile time error?

Comment: Yes it is a compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you are trying to assign directly to the content height and width which is not allowed. You can only set the .contentSize (which is made up of the width and height).

Are you trying to change the content size or the actually scroll view size?

If you want to change the scroll view size, you have to change the frame, not the content size.

To change the frame you would want to do something similar to this:

```
self.mainScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: self.mainScrollView.frame.origin.x, y: self.mainScrollView.frame.origin.y, width: UIScreen.mainScreent().bounds.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
```

You should also put that in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method.

With all that said, you should be able to accomplish this via constraints in the storyboard.

After viewing your content it appears that you are looking for something more along these lines:

```
self.mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: self.mainScrollView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: I'm trying to change the size of the actual content view. In the nib file it has a set width and isn't inside the view outlet, so I can't add constraints for the width. So, when I load the scrollview on a phone simulator smaller than an iPhone 6+ the scrollview has a horizontal scroll as well as a vertical scroll. I only want it to be able to scroll vertically and have the contentView constrained to the sides of the scrollView.

Comment: See my latest edit. It should constrain the width while keeping the height the same

Comment: I've tried that but it just causes part of my contentView to be cut off, since i can't scroll horizontally to see it.

Comment: Try both. Set the frame and the content size and see if that helps.

Comment: Still having the same issue on smaller screen sizes. The issue isn't with the mainScrollView, the issue is with the contentView. The contentView can't have constraints set in the NIB file since it is a top level view that I add into the view outlet's mainScrollView with addSubview. I'm trying to find a way to alter the contentView's width to adjust to the width of the different screen sizes.

Comment: E.G: Frame of the iPhone 6 is 375 pts. wide. The frame of an iPhone 6+ is 414 points wide. In the nib file the contentView is 414 points wide on all screen sizes, since it is a top level view and cannot have constraints added to it. So, when it is added to smaller screens the width is greater than the screen width so there is horizontal scrolling as well as vertical scrolling when my goal is to have the width of the contentView scale to the UIScreen.mainScreen width to make it only scroll vertically.